# panelGroup without style or styleClass is not rendered unless ID is given

Tags: jsf

According to the tag library for http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html, a `h:panelGroup` is

> Intended for use in situations when only one
>               UIComponent child can be nested, such as in the case of facets.
>               If the "style" or "styleClass" attributes are present, and the
>               "layout"
>               attribute is present with a value of "block", render a "div"
>               element,
>               outputting the value of the "style" attribute as the value of the
>               "style" attribute and the value of the "styleClass" attribute as the
>               value of the "class" attribute. Otherwise, if the "layout" attribute
>               is not present, or the "layout" attribute contains a value other
>               than
>               "block", render a "span" element, outputting the value of the
>               "style" attribute as the value of the "style" attribute, and the
>               value
>               of the "styleClass" attribute as the value of the "class"
>               attribute.

In case of

```
<h:panelGroup id="id" layout="block">
    <!-- ... --->
</h:panelGroup>
```

or

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <!-- ... --->
</h:panelGroup>
```

a `div` is being rendered:

```
<div id="id">
</div>
```

respective

```
<div style="margin-right: 10px;">
</div>
```

but when omitting the `id` (if one don't want to `update` the `panelGroup`) or the `style` (if one don't want to style the `panelGroup`) no `div` is being rendered and the resulting HTML can mess up ones layout. Furthermore exploring the realm of JSF, a `panelGroup` can also be used to conditionally render child elements using its `rendered` flag but as mentioned before when omitting the two mentioned attributes the result is rendered conditionally but without a `div`, such as

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="true">
<it>Without DIV.</it>
</h:panelGroup>
```

leads to

```
<it>Without DIV.</it>
```

After this inquiry I want to check with the Stackoverflow community that I understood it right that when not using a `panelGroup` as a naming container or to customary style its elements one is better off solving the conditional rendering part (if needed) using a `ui:fragment` and the layouting part with a hard-coded `div`. Is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: we are talking about if `h:panelgroup` will render any HTML component, but unless `render="false"` the inner components are not blocked from rendering in any case.

The behaviour tree of `h:panelgroup` consists of two checks:

1. Is at least one of "id" or "style" or "styleClass" attributes set?
    **Yes:**
    a. Renders a `<div>` if layout="block", **otherwise**
    b. Renders a `<span>` (layout="*gibberish*" or non-existant)

   **No:**
2. Renders no html component. Still useful if you want to use "rendered" or when you can nest only one component (i.e. `<f:facet>`)

The test for the layout attribute only comes after **1.**, above. Since your third example goes into the **no** branch, it is ignored.

Comment: Would it be it be according specs that the `rendered` is ignored if the attributes mentioned in 1 are not present? So a `<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="false">BLA</h:panelGroup>` is always rendered? (cannot check the source of an implementation or the specs from my phone now...) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611107/hpanelgroup-body-still-executed-when-rendered-attribut-evaluate-to-false

Comment: @Kukeltje the rendered attribute set to false will block render both of the div/span and of the inner components to that `<h:panelGroup>` - what the question addresses is not the control of the rendering of the component, is one of behaviour.